# How do I install emacs on windows?

Tags: windows, emacs

I downloaded the tar file [emacs-24.3.tar.gz](http://mirror.anl.gov/pub/gnu/emacs/) and I extracted it. I look at the installation instructions [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/efaq-w32.html#Installing):

> You can run Emacs without any extra steps, but if you want icons in
>   your Start Menu, or for Emacs to detect the image libraries that are
>   already installed on your system as part of GTK, then you should run
>   the program emacs-24.3\bin\addpm.exe.

How do I run Emacs?

And where is `emacs-24\bin\addpm.exe`. In the folder `emacs-24` there is no `bin` folder. So how do I run emacs after installation?

Comment: Note that you could have checked the download instruction from the same page: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/efaq-w32.html#Downloading

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Download windows binaries here:

http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/windows/

`.tar.gz`s are usually linux sources, so you'll have to compile it if you download that.

Comment: I would suggest using http://ftpmirror.gnu.org/emacs/windows/ instead, which should redirect you to a nearby mirror. The current release is `emacs-24.3-bin-i386.zip` (and in general, that's the filename pattern to look for).

Comment: @JSON If you believe this answer to be incorrect please add a comment or a competing answer

Comment: What about bleeding edge binaries?

Comment: How to compile that .tar.gz, as mentioned by the @simonzack in the answer.